# changes after 20.04 upgrade

Tags: upgrade, 20.04

I have another annoying little issue which has reared it's head after upgrading from 18..04 to 20.04:
When I open the 'About Computer' window it opens larger than the display on which it is displayed (see screenshot).
I would appreciate any assistance on this matter -- yes, I know how to re-size the window, and I know how to close it, but I would like to know WHY it is happening and how to stop it!
Many Thanks

[image]

this issue only seems to occur with one user account, so may be specific to that, if so, where are the settings that control the specific user acount?

edit: I created another user account, logged into gnome flashback(metacity)and the window opened normally.

further edit: logging in with my original user account to gnome flashback (compiz) and the system settings window opened normally.

Comment: Can't reproduce this. For me, the window opens smaller, and the content is scrollable. Is this plain Gnome Classic or do you have specific extensions installed? If yes, try whether disabling them solves the issue.

Comment: @vanadium it's GNOME Flashback(metacity), issue wasn't present last week when i was running 18.04, only apparent now I'm on 20.04.1

Comment: Possibly "upgrade pain" (yet I also upgraded myself, alt least from 19.04 over 19.10). You could temporarily create a new account and see if it happens there, to see whether it is a system issue or a user specific configuration issue.

Comment: @vanadium i created another account, and the issue isnt there, interestingly, i'm also having issues with removing the home and trash icons from the desktop, which were not apparent when i tried the other account. is there somewhere where i can see the configuration for a specific user?

Comment: This already confines the issue somewhat. Would be good to add that information to your actual question: use "edit". User configuration is stored in configuration files, either as hidden files or under hidden folders in the home folder  in the home folder.

Comment: @vanadium yes, i understand that the user configurations are stored in the config files, my question is where and what are the settings that control this? (other windows dont open in this way)

Comment: Was the other account where it did not happen also configured with Gnome Flashback and metacity? The more you can confine the problem yourself, the more a specific cause and resolution may be found. I do not know what is specifically controlling the size of that window.

Comment: yes, i set it up, logged into gnome flashback(metacity) and the window opened normally!

Comment: OK, add this to your question, because comments can disappear.